# Dropdown 'select' list not populating from mysql database query. Where is my error?

Tags: php, mysql

Why is my dropdown list not populating?  I hope someone can point to my error.

My page renders correctly and I see the dropdown list but I contains only one entry i.e. "select an event".

Where am I going wrong?

Tony

Current Code:

```
<form class="form" action="http://host/ants/connie/addExhibit.php" method="post">
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Add New Exhibit Record:</legend>
              Choose Event :
              <select name="event">
                     <option value="" selected>select an event</option>
                     <?php
                     $con=mysqli_connect("server","root","pw","db");
                     //check connection
                     if (mysqli_connect_error())
                             {
                             echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                             }
                     $sql="select id, name from event order by name";
                     $result = mysqli_query($con,"$sql");
                     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                             {
                     echo "<option value = \"" . $row['id'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>"
                     ?>
                     <?php
                     }
                     ?>
             </select><br>
              Choose Exhibitor :      <input type="text" size="30" name="exhibitor" /><br>
              Exhibit Name:           <input type="text" size="30" name="venue" /><br>
              Price:                  <input type="text" size="30" name="convenor" /><br>
              Sold:                   <input type="text" size="30" name="email" /><br>
      <input type="submit">
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Missing `;` at the end of `echo "<option value = \"" . $row['id'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>"`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` which would have signaled the error.

Comment: Plus, you may want to get rid of the quotes for `$result = mysqli_query($con,"$sql");`

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply.  I implemented each of your suggestions but still the drop down does not populate.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You're welcome. Did you use the error reporting above? Also, view your HTML source, you will see what it looks like and where you might have used the wrong type of quotes, or missing some.

Comment: Try this `echo "<option value = '".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";` that should work.

Comment: One thing that might be worth checking - you're using `mysqli_fetch_array`. That returns an indexed array of values, but you're trying to access it as an associative array. Maybe try with `$row[0]` instead? That said, I'm not sure what the default return style is for that function, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: @andrewsi I was thinking the same thing as well. Yet my example above is borrowed from a piece of code I use with PDO being `while ($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`, so the OP should be using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` then.

Comment: after implementing `echo     "<option value = '".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";`     what I see in my drop down list is .$row['name'].    but I am not seeing the value from my query.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array result in both indexed and associative both, You can use either it does not matter..

Comment: Try this instead:

`echo "<option value='{$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";`

Comment: Why in the world are you closing your while statement in a separate set of PHP tags?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Kirk.  after implementing your suggestion I am seeing the same result.  my dropdown box displays .$row['name'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Its working fine with mysql_connect, You can do it in mysqli_connect way too.

```
<?php
$connect=new connect("server","root","pw","db");
class connect{
     function __construct($host,$user,$password,$db_name){
        mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die("Connection error");
        mysql_select_db($db_name);
        $error=mysql_error();
        if (!empty($error))
        {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
}
$query=mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM event ORDER BY name");         
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Check Dropdown</title>
</head>
<body>
<form >

            <fieldset>
              <legend>Get the drop down Value </legend>

              <select class="form-control input-sm" name="branch">
                    <option value="">Select</option>

                     <?php 
                      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
                        {
                            echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                  </select>
               </fieldset>
          </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance, my form is now doing what I had hoped for.